# Identity Server 3 Access Token Validation endpoint fails with Audience Validation Failed

Tags: validation, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, identityserver3

I have an IdentityServer3 instance set up and I am requesting a token using the authorize endpoint (/core/connect/authorize).

My application requesting the token is an iOS application.

I pass the following parameters;

```
client_id=<clientid>
response_type=id_token
scope=openid
redirect_uri=<redirecturi>
state=<state>
nonce=<nonce>
```

This then opens up a web view for me, I enter my credentials and it returns the `redirect_uri` with the `#id_token` appended to the url.

To validate the token I pass it to the access token validation endpoint (/core/connect/accesstokenvalidation) of my IdentityServer. I append `?token=<access token received from login>`.

I then get the response

```
{ "Message": "invalid_token" }
```

When I check the log

```
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audience: '<clientid>'. Did not match: validationParamters.ValidAudience: '<identity_server_host>/resources' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: 'null'
```

What am I doing wrong here? Surely the IdentityServer that created the token should validate it as valid?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes, see below the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't request an access token in your example.
With

```
response_type=id_token
```

you only get the identity token which you can validate against the identity token endpoint.
To get the access token with your request you must change your request to

```
response_type=id_token token
```